# How well does m2eclipse deal with maven plugins?

Tags: maven-2, m2eclipse

In general, how well does m2eclipse deal with Maven plugins that modify or amend lifecycle phases?

In particular, I have a project that has a maven-clean-plugin extension to remove an extra generated directory (not in `target/`) using the configuration filesets tag.  This works when running mvn at the command line but not when doing a clean in Eclipse.  Is there any way to get m2eclipse to process that plugin?

Another example is flexmojos; there's a lot that can be configured with the flexmojo plugin but those parameters don't seem to get imported by m2eclipse.

Is the integration solely ad-hoc?  If m2eclipse embeds Maven, why can't the plugins be executed directly using the underlying pom.xml configuration?

Answer (score 0):

> In general, how well does m2eclipse deal with Maven plugins that modify or amend lifecycle phases?

Decently, to my experience. At least for plugin bound to phases from the [default lifecycle](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html).

> In particular, I have a project that has a maven-clean-plugin extension (...). This works when running mvn at the command line but not when doing a clean in Eclipse. Is there any way to get m2eclipse to process that plugin?

What the clean plugin "extension" is doing and what you're doing (calling `mvn clean` from Eclipse? calling **Project > Clean**?) is unclear - at least for me. But maybe have a look at [MNGECLIPSE-823](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/MNGECLIPSE-823) or [MNGECLIPSE-156](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/MNGECLIPSE-156). And don't hesitate to clarify :)

> Another example is flexmojos; there's a lot that can be configured with the flexmojo plugin but those parameters don't seem to get imported by m2eclipse.

I don't do flex so the above is too vague for me. But providing a more concrete example might help.

Comment: I'm using "Project > Clean" from Eclipse; MNGECLIPSE-156 looks promising.  With regards to FlexMojos, I'll hunt down a better example too.  Thanks!

Comment: @Emil Yes, you'll need MNGECLIPSE-156 as Project > Clean doesn't trigger the clean lifecycle.